# INSERT/UPDATE PHP variables together with values of other tables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, extjs, extjs4

I have a table called `Users`. This table holds the parameters: `userID`, `userName`, `functionID`, `supervisorID`, `firstName`, `lastName` and `email`.

When I load the users into my application, created with EXT JS, I use the following query in PHP:

```
public function getEmployees(stdClass $params)
{
    global $DBH;
    $STH = $DBH->query(
        "SELECT u.id, u.userName AS 'userName', f.functionName, us.userName AS 'supervisorName', u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email 
         FROM users AS u 
         INNER JOIN functions AS f ON u.functionID=f.id
         LEFT JOIN users AS us ON u.supervisorID=us.id 
         ORDER BY u.id");
    return $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

So instead of passing through the `functionID` and `supervisorID` I pass through the `functionName`and `supervisorName`.
My grid on my application displays the `userName`, `functionName` (not ID), `supervisorName` (not ID), `firstName`,...

Now I'm breaking my head on how to create a new user and how to update a user if my application passes the `userName`, `functionName` (so this needs to be converted to the `functionID`), `supervisorName` (needs to be converted to `supervisorID`), `firstName`,...
I have tried numberous queries but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

**Update after comments:**
I should have mentioned that my site is built with EXT JS from Sencha.
Only an administrator can edit or create new users.
The creating/editing is done in an EXT Grid and the JSON data is passed to PHP with Ext.Direct.
So I need a way to get the `functionID` and `supervisorID` associated with the `functionName` and `supervisorID` passed by the application.

Comment: Why can't you select also `functionID`and `supervisorID` in your first query?

Comment: @Uby What I mean is: when I create a user on my website I pass the username, functionname (not the functionID), supervisorname (not the userID),... to PHP. But the functionName needs to be converted to the associated functionID in order to insert it into the users table. Feel free to ask me questions if my explanation is not complete.

Comment: User creation is something you do via form? Is something a common user of your application can do or something allowed only to administrators?

Comment: @Uby User creation is something only administrators can do with an EXT JS grid

Comment: if you are using functionname and supervisorname in to link in your database you are doing it wrong? are these values always unique? if so why do you need IDs these should be your IDs.

Comment: @TheCellarRoom I'm not sure what you're saying, sorry, I'm just a beginning developer. I'm using the `functionID` to link to a `functions` table which holds the `functionID` and the `functionName`

Comment: but in your form to create a user you are using functionName, why?

Comment: @TheCellarRoom Because in my grid at the functionName column I use a combobox which holds all the functionNames (loaded from the `functions` table). So an administrator just has to select the function of the employee in stead of looking or the correct ID

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your form has combo box (`<select>`) or similar control (radio button set, list) to select the function and supervisor. Make the value of the `select` the ID, not the name:

```
<select name="function">
    <option value="1">Boss</option>
    <option value="2">Stableman</option>
    <option value="3">Servant</option>
    <option value="4">Shepherd</option>
</select>
```

Then you do not need to do any mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the website is build with Ext JS from Sencha. So the data is sent from a Grid. In the Grid administrators can set the username, functionname,... So the conversion needs to be done in the query, not on the website.

Comment: Not sure I really understand. Anyway, you definitelly need to update your question a lot to get answers you look for.

Answer (score 0):

Martin is right, that's a client side issue. You'd rather post a question with your ExtJS code if you don't know how to configure your components in order to make them submit the ids in the request.

For a starter, you should use `valueField` and `displayField` options for the [combo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox), coupled with a [column renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) to display the name instead of the id in the grid, even when the user isn't editing (i.e. the cell isn't rendered with the combo).